# Кодировка в названии прикрепленного вложения IBM Notes

Tags: java, файлы, веб-служба, mime, ibm

Добрый день.
Имеется веб-сервис, который импортирует файл `.doc` в документ `NotesDocument`. Проблема в том, что если название файла на русском, то в названии вложения получаю иероглифы. Само содержание корректное.

```
File directory = new File("C:\\Attachments 1C");
String filename = "Безымянный.png"
String path = directory + "\\" + filename;
Stream outStream = sess.createStream();
sess.setConvertMIME(true);
MIMEEntity body = newDoc.createMIMEEntity("rtBody");

Stream inStream = sess.createStream();
if (inStream.open(path, "UTF-8")) {
    if (inStream.getBytes() > 0) {
        do {
            byte[] buffer = inStream.read(32767);
            outStream.write(buffer);
        } while (!inStream.isEOS());
        inStream.close();

        MIMEEntity child = body.createChildEntity();

        String fileSuffix = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

        child.setContentFromBytes(outStream, fileSuffix, MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT);

        MIMEHeader header = child.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
        header.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        header = child.createHeader("Content-ID");
        header.setHeaderVal(path);
        outStream.truncate();
    }else 
        return "Пустой файла";
}else 
    return "Не удалось открыть файл";
```

Например, если `filename = "Безымянный.png"`, то к документу `newDoc` он прикрепляется под названием `"Áåçûìÿííûé.png"`.

Comment: Из вашего кода непонятно откуда берётся `filename` и `path`, каким образом файл прикрепляется к новому документу.

Comment: добавил переменные. файл прикрепляется через MIME. этот код работает, но проблема с кодировкой в названии прикрепленного файла

Comment: Здесь я вижу имя файла  - константа, а хотелось бы понять где вы берёте оригинальное имя файла. Оно приходит вместе с самим файлом в web-сервис или вы его "придумываете" сами? Если вывести имя файла в консоль (System.out.println()), в каком виде оно выводится? Надо сначала разобраться получает ли ваш код уже повреждённое имя или оно записывается в MIME секцию с неправильной кодировкой.

Comment: имя приходит в виде строки и оно правильное. проверено. проблема именно в том, что записывается оно в неправильной кодировке в MIME секцию, хотя содержимое файла правильное

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась с помощью MimeEncode:

```
String filenameEndoded = MimeUtility.encodeText(filename,"UTF-8","B");
```